# Empirical Likelihood estimation in R

Tags: r, likelihood, empirical-likelihood

I'm new to Empirical Likelihood Estimation.

I'm trying to find an example of how to find the empirical likelihood estimate of a univariate mean $\mu$ using the `emplik` software package in `R`.

Any help or reference is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we have a random variable $X$ with expectation $\mu$ and we want to test $H_0 : \mu = 0$.

We can test this by

```
el.test(x, mu=0)
```

This will give us the log likelihood ratio  $-2 \sum (\log(n p_i))$ and $p$ value.

Then you can decide about your hypothesis.

Comment: Could you write a little bit more because from your answer it is not even clear what is `el.test` function and what are the `n`, `p`, `i` values in log likelihood function.

Answer (score -4):

maximum empirical likelihood estimate, in the iid case, is the sample mean.

empirical likelihood method helps you to find a confidence interval.

Comment: Could you provide a working example with R code, as requested by the OP?